# zend framework 1 how to set a form fiels as select from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, zend-framework

I have an input form which linked a database table  one of the field is set to a dropdown list from  anotther table  in other words i want the field  id_`magasin` to be selected from table `magasin` this  is  the code
in this case it shows id `magasin` as empty

```
   <?php

class Application_Form_Produit extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
       $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
        $id->addFilter('Int');
        $nom = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('nom');
        $nom->setLabel('Nom du produit')
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->addFilter('StripTags')
        ->addFilter('StringTrim')
        ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $prix_unitaire = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('prix_unitaire');
        $prix_unitaire->setLabel('prix_unitaire')
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->addFilter('StripTags')
        ->addFilter('StringTrim')
        ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $id_magasin = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('id_magasin'.'magasin');
        $id_magasin->setLabel('Magasin')
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->addFilter('StripTags')
        ->addFilter('StringTrim')
        ->addValidator('NotEmpty');

        $mag = new Application_Model_DbTable_Magasin();
        $data = $mag->getAll();
        foreach($data as $d){
            $id_magasin->addMultiOption($d->id_magasin);



        $envoyer = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('envoyer');
        $envoyer->setAttrib('id','boutonenvoyer');
        $this->addElements(array($id, $nom, $prix_unitaire,$id_magasin, $envoyer));
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a display value for your dropdown options. Change:

```
$id_magasin->addMultiOption($d->id_magasin);
```

to

```
$id_magasin->addMultiOption($d->id_magasin, $d->id_magasin);
```

to show the id in the select.

Also, I do not know if you have a function "getAll()" in your Application_Model_DbTable_Magasin or if you are extending Zend_Db_Table_Abstract but the default function inherited by Zend_Db_Table_Abstract is fetchAll(). Maybe you also have to replace that.

Comment: Thank u very much  how about if i have second field that also dependant to magasin  I mean once id_magasin selected another field called adresse will be filled automatically with adresse  from magasin  Thank u again